# Puppeteer goto with query parameters does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, goto

I am using Puppeteer `page.goto(url)` to to navigate to a page **that ends with with `.html?page=2`**

So a page I would call would look something like this:

```
https://www.billa.at/search/results?category=&searchTerm=brot&page=2
```

Here is my code:

```js
  const browser = await Puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto(url)
  console.log(page.url())
```

Unfortunately the query params are ignored. When I log `page.url()` the return value is the page that I have called without the query params which looks like this:

```
https://www.billa.at/search/results?category=&searchTerm=brot
```

Executing `page.goto(url, { waitUntil: [anyhting] })` results in a timeout

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using 'body-parser' by any chance ?

Comment: @Arka no, I am not. Only `puppeteer`, `nodemon`, and a few babel packages

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce - when I try with `https://example.com/some-category.html?page=2`, `page.url()` returns the full url with query parameters as expected. What do you see in the address bar when launching puppeteer using `puppeteer.launch({headless: false});`? Is there any chance you're being redirected? Are you able to provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Unfortunately I wasnt able to get back to you until today. I have updated my question with minimal code and an example page

Comment: @AnzorAsadov one thing that might be happening is the page is reacting to the category being empty. When I run your example without the category it succeeds to keep the page parameter.

Comment: I'm still unable to reproduce using your example code and URL above - it successfully navigates to the URL and the console output is the full URL with the query parameters. Is it maybe an older version of puppeteer? I'm using 5.5.0

Comment: I had the same issue and the cause in my case was that the goto was following a redirect that I didn't realize was there, which was stripping the query string. Specifically, I was pointed at an HTTP address that redirected to HTTPS.